# Can I use Application.yml in Spring mvc in the same way as of boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, yaml

I have seen no of programmers, using application.yml file for some global information in spring boot. In Spring boot, You don't need to read this file explicitly. For example :

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username:
    password:
```

Now You don't need to read and then set these values while making connection. My Question is, Can I do so in Spring MVC? Please Explain Why and How?

Comment: Why don't you use Spring Boot?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Dear, It is an old project written in MVC, will take lot of time.